# Show that the following sequence converges to 0

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$X := \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(n+n)^2}$$
Show the above sequence converges to $0$

I was able to prove the above sequence converges :
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4n^2} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$
thus by comparison test the above sequence converges.
$$\\$$But I wasn't able to prove it converges to $0$? Solution or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: _Hint_: You have $n$ terms, and each one can be bounded by $1/n^2$ from above.

Comment: $$X_n := \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(n+n)^2}$$

$$ \leq n\cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n} \to 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty. $$

Comment: Got it, thank you